# Remove all falsy values from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to remove all falsy values from an array. Falsy values in JavaScript are false, null, 0, "", undefined, and NaN.

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
 arr = arr.filter(function (n) { 
    return (n !== undefined && n !== null && n !== false && n !== 0 && n !== "" && isNaN()!=NaN); });
  return arr;
}

bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9, NaN], "");
```

The above is getting satisfied for all except the NaN test case. Can someone help me check in the array whether it contains NaN or not?

Answer (score 231):

You can use Boolean :

```
var myFilterArray = myArray.filter(Boolean);
```

Comment: Boolean is the constructor for, well, booleans. This is equivalent to `var myFilterArray = myArray.filter((v) => new Boolean(v));`. If the given value is `0`, `-0` (I know...), `null`, `false`, `NaN`, `undefined`, or the empty string, the resulting Boolean will be `false`. If anything else is passed, it'll be `true`.

Comment: @LoremIpsum: If you try that, you’ll notice it never filters out anything, because `Boolean` used as a *constructor* creates boolean wrapper objects (JavaScript’s stupidest feature, serving no purpose at all) which are always truthy. `Boolean(v)` instead of `new Boolean(v)`, which is what passing `Boolean` directly achieves, casts to boolean.

Comment: @LoremIpsum It’s equivalent to `var myFilterArray = myArray.filter((v) => Boolean(v));`, without the `new`. `new Boolean` would create Boolean objects which are truthy, meaning that `filter` accepts all elements, which in turn would be equivalent to `var myFilterArray = myArray.filter(() => true);`.

Comment: Oh, why is this at the very bottom? I just posted this because all the answers seemed tricky

Comment: What about performance? Seems like this approach is extremely slow, because it needs to construct `Boolean` for each element. Also it is less compact than `.filter(x=>x)`

Answer (score 63):

Since you want to get rid of "falsy" values, just let JavaScript do its thing:

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(v) { return !!v; });
}
```

The double-application of the  `!` operator will make the filter callback return `true` when the value is "truthy" and `false` when it's "falsy".

(Your code is calling `isNaN()` but not passing it a value; that's why that test didn't work for you. The `isNaN()` function returns `true` if its parameter, when coerced to a number, is `NaN`, and `false` otherwise.)

*edit* — note that

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.filter(Boolean);
}
```

would work too as LoremIpsum notes in another answer, because the built-in Boolean constructor does pretty much the exact same thing as `!!`.

Comment: Excellent. Nice technique for functional method

Comment: isn't this { return !!v; } the same as { return v; }

Comment: Technically you don't even need the `!!` here because `filter` is testing for truthiness, not comparison to `true`.

Answer (score 33):

```
truthyArray = arr.filter(el => el)
```

^ that's how you do it

Comment: curly braces disable implicit return, so you'll get empty array.

Answer (score 20):

Using this simple filter will do:

`array.filter(Boolean)`

You can read more about `Boolean` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)

Comment: Simple and best solution!

Answer (score 9):

You use `isNaN()` in wrong way. It should be something like following:

```
function bouncer(arr) {
   return arr.filter(function (n) { 
       return n !== undefined && n !== null && n !== false && n !== 0 && n !== "" && !isNaN(n); 
   });
```

}

Also you can rewrite it:

```
function bouncer( arr ){
    return arr.filter( function( value ){
        return value;
    });
}
```

Comment: the above code works perfectly ... can you explain me what is happening in the return arr.filter( function( value ){
        return value;
    });

Comment: @Vignesh Array.prototype.filter checks if value is truthy and then adds it to array. All values above are not truthy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: in the first case, filter is removing strings even if they are not empty, why?

Answer (score 5):

This is another equivalent, but illustrative, solution:

```
function bouncer( arr ){
    return arr.filter( function( value ){
        return value ? true : false;
    });
}
```

This code sample is illustrative because it indicates to a reader that the variable `value` will be evaluated as truthy or falsey, and the anonymous function will return a boolean, either `true` or `false`, mapping to the evaluation of `value`.

For someone who is not familiar with this approach of removing values from an array based on their truthiness, or for someone who is not familiar with (or has not read the documentation on) the `filter` function, this example is the most concise that still conveys the behavior of the `filter` function.

Of course, in your application you may opt for the more concise, yet less insightful, implementation:

```
function bouncer( arr ){
    return arr.filter( function( value ){
        return value;
    });
}
```

Comment: `x ? true : false` is always redundant. `return value` is enough. In some cases you need to use `Boolean(value)` or `!!value`, but not this case.

Comment: I wrote this answer thinking that it illustrates that `filter` evaluates the value based on a boolean return value.  Without explicitly stating that `filter `evaluates the callback's return value as a boolean, then `return value;` will not be sufficient in expressing the concept to someone that is new to the `filter` function.

Comment: Having this kind of illustration makes it easier to read the code.

Answer (score 5):

Using filter we can write

```
function bouncer(arr) {
 return arr.filter(item => item);
}
bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]) // will return [].
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this can be done using the arr.filter() method. But I prefer using the Boolean() function. Is clearer to me. Here's how I did it, although a little longer:

```
function bouncer(arr) {
// Don't show a false ID to this bouncer.

    var falsy;
    var trueArr = [];

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        falsy =  Boolean(arr[i]);

        if (falsy === true) {

        trueArr.push(arr[i]);

        }

    }

    return trueArr;
}

bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
// returns a new array that is filtered accordingly.
```

Answer (score 3):

I think a better deal this way

```
   function bouncer(arr) {
        arr = arr.filter(function(item) {
            return item;
        return arr;

    bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9, NaN, undefined, 0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

bouncer function:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.filter((val) => {
    return !!val;
  });
}

console.log(bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]));
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all working answers above. Here are 3 approaches to solve the problem. Third solution addressed problem by your approach @Vignesh.

```
1. 
function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.filter( function( val ){
        return val;
    });
}

2. 
function bouncer(arr) {
return arr.filter(Boolean);
}
3.
  function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(val){
      return val !== false && val !== "" && !(Number.isNaN(val)) && val !== 
undefined && val !== 0 && val !== null;
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just negate twice to "cast" to boolean. `!NaN === true` => `!!NaN === false`

```
    const truthy = arr.filter(o => !!o)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my idea...

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  // Don't show a false ID to this bouncer.
  var result = [];
  
    function isGood(obj){
      if(!Boolean(obj)){
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
    
    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
      if (isGood(arr[i]) === true){
        result.push(arr[i]);
      }
    }
  return result;
}

console.log(bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using filter and Boolean:

```
let array = [7,"ate","",false,9];
array.filter((values) => {return Boolean(values) === true })
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like to use JS utility libraries like [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) or [Underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/) you can use the `compact` function.

```
import _ from 'lodash' // or import _ from 'underscore'

_.compact([0, 1, false, 'hello', '', {}, null]) // returns [1, 'hello', {}]
```

#### Documentation:

- [Lodash `.compact`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#compact).
- [Underscore `.compact`](https://underscorejs.org/#compact).

Answer (score 2):

#### Falsy values

- false
- zero(0,-0)
- empty string(“”, ‘ ‘ , ` `)
- BigIntZero(0,0x0n)
- null
- undefined
- NaN

```js
const values = [false,'false','js', true, 0 , [],[1,2,3], 1, 'b', {}, 
'', NaN, undefined, null, -5,1n,0n,0x1n,0x0n];

console.log(values.filter((value)=> !!value));
console.log(values.filter((value) => value ));
console.log(values.filter((value)=> Boolean(value)));
console.log(values.filter(Boolean));

//=> [ 'false', 'js', true, [], [ 1, 2, 3 ], 1, 'b', {}, -5, 1n, 1n ]
```

```js
// note: empty collections are not falsy like in python (empty array)
//note: will syntax error for 1x0n, 'false' is string here
const values = [false,'false','js', true, 0 , [],[1,2,3], 1, 'b', {}, '', NaN, undefined, null, -5,1n,0n,0x1n,0x0n];
//=> [ 'false', 'js', true, [], [ 1, 2, 3 ], 1, 'b', {}, -5, 1n, 1n ]
//=> [ 'false', 'js', true, [], [ 1, 2, 3 ], 1, 'b', {}, -5, null, null ] // BigInt not supported compilers

// double not 
// first not makes it as boolean opposite values, then  second not give its inversion
console.log(values.filter(
  (value)=> !!value
));

// Auto Coercion 
// values are self identified as falsy or not
console.log(values.filter(
  value => value
));

// Boolean type conversion
// get values as parem and return boolean as falsy or not
console.log(values.filter(
  (value)=> Boolean(value)
));

// Boolean constructor
// This works because Boolean itself is a function, and the arguments filter supplies are passed directly to it
console.log(values.filter(
  Boolean
));
```

For Detailed explanation refer : [samanthaming website](https://www.samanthaming.com/pictorials/how-to-remove-all-falsy-values-from-an-array/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function bouncer(arr) {  
  var result = []; 
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if (arr[i]) {
      result.push(arr[i]);
     }
   }
  return result;
 }

 bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function falsy(value) {
      if (value) {
        return value;
      }
    }

    function bouncer(arr) {
      var filter = arr.filter(falsy);
      return filter;
    }

    bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeFalsy(value){

  var val = Boolean(value);
  if(!val)
    return false;
  return true;
}

function bouncer(arr) {

  return arr.filter(removeFalsy);
}

bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
let array = [7, 'ate', '', false, 9, NaN];

function removeFalsyItems(array) {
   // Your result
   let filter = array.filter(Boolean);

   // Empty the array
   array.splice(0, array.length);

   // Push all items from the result to our array
   Array.prototype.push.apply(array, filter);

   return array
}

removeFalsyItems(array) // => [7, 'ate', 9], funny joke btw...
```

Comment: You could also turn it into an array method via `Array.prototype` to make it more convenient e.g.: `[1, 0, 1].removeFalsyItems() // => [1, 1]`

Answer (score 1):

```
myArray = [false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""];
myArray.map(item => {
//if you want you can write logic
        console.log(item);
    })
    // Get rid of bad values
    .filter(Boolean);
```

it will return [].

Answer (score 1):

I see you never accepted an answer. Is the problem that you are relying on Logger.log or console.log to see if the null removal worked? I think the filter suggested by @LoremIpsum is the cleanest solution.

```
  const src2DArr = [[34], [75], [30], [48], [976], [], [178], [473], [51], [75], [29], [47], [40]];
  Logger.log("src2DArr: " +JSON.stringify(src2DArr)); 
  // [[34],[75],[30],[48],[976],[],[178],[473],[51],[75],[29],[47],[40]]
  
  var src2DArr1 = src2DArr.filter(Boolean);
  Logger.log("src2DArr1: " + JSON.stringify(src2DArr1));
  // [[34],[75],[30],[48],[976],[],[178],[473],[51],[75],[29],[47],[40]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.filter`

```
myArray.filter(val => Boolean(val));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function bouncer(arr) {

    function filterFalse(value) {
        var a = Boolean(value);
        if (a === true) {
            return a;
        }
        return a;
    }

    function filterArray(x) {
        var y = filterFalse(x);
        if (y) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    var newArr = arr.filter(filterArray);
    return newArr;
}

bouncer([1, null, NaN, 2, undefined]);
```

Answer (score 0):

removing false values from array with **ECMAscript 5** Vanila JS

```
function bouncer(arr){
  let trueArray = [];
  for(int i=0; i<arr.lenght; i++){
    if(arr[i]===true){
      trueArray.push(arr[i]);
    }    
  }
  return trueArray;
}
```

removing false values from array using **ECMAscript6** or **Ecma2015** method

```
function bouncer(arr){
   let trueArray = arr.filter( item => item===true);
  return trueArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function compact(ar) {
  let newArr = []
  for (let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    if (
      !(
        ar[i] === false ||
        ar[i] === null ||
        ar[i] === 0 ||
        ar[i] === '' ||
        ar[i] === undefined ||
        (typeof ar[i] == 'number' && !ar[i])
      )
    ) {
      newArr.push(ar[i])
    }
  }
  return newArr
}
```