# How does the indexOf method is returning the falsely value?

Tags: javascript

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  var array = [false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""];
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (array.indexOf(arr[i]) === -1) {
          result.push(arr[i]);
      }
  }
  return result;
}
ex : bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]) should return [7, "ate", 9].
```

Hello Everyone, 
I am trying to delete all the falsely values that are in the array input, but for somehow when I run `bouncer([false,null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]);` I get `[NaN]` as a return value while I am expecting an empty array. Does anyone know why the function is returning the falsely values ?

Comment: `NaN` is not equal to itself.

Comment: This is a Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906887/remove-all-falsy-values-from-an-array

Comment: Actually `if (!!arr[i])` works even for NaN

Comment: NaN is an object in the global space. In .js NaN is not equal to itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned - `NaN` is (by design) not equal to anything (not even itself).

To solve your problem you can add the `arr[i] === arr[i]` to your `if(...)`:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  var array = [false, null, 0, undefined, ""];
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (array.indexOf(arr[i]) === -1 && (arr[i] === arr[i])) {
          result.push(arr[i]);
      }
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]));
console.log(bouncer([false,null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]));
```

Answer (score 5):

It's because `NaN` is really a *concept* rather than a concrete number.

Consider the two "numbers" `0 / 0` and `sqrt(-1)`. Neither of these are defined in the real number space so both give `NaN`, but they are clearly different values.

Because `NaN` basically indicates an unknown value that couldn't be represented in IEEE-754, it is never considered equal to another `NaN`, *even itself.*

This is the right thing to do because, given the infinitude (literally) of numbers that have no real representation in IEEE-754, the chances of two of them being the same number are infinitesimally small :-)

In fact, many implementations of `isNaN()` depend on this feature, to wit (pseudo-code):

```
define isNaN(n):
    return n != n
```

---

To actually *solve* this problem, one way is to remove the `NaN` from the checking array and slightly modify the conditional:

```
var array = [false, null, 0, undefined, ""];
:
if ((array.indexOf(arr[i]) === -1) && (! isNaN(arr[i])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already an answer that explains why `NaN` is included in your result. As to a solution to your problem, the following should suffice:

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  return Array.isArray(arr) ? arr.filter(v => v) : undefined;
}
```

The idea here is we filter out the values which coerce to `true` in a boolean context. Thus, the function we use to filter just returns the value itself!