# How to remove false values from array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I receive this in console

```
0: false
1: false
2: false
3: false
4: false
5: "scuole"
6: "scuole"
7: "scuole"
8: "scuole"
```

I need to remove all `false` and I have been trying to follow [this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906887/remove-all-falsy-values-from-an-array)

and I tried

```
    var scuole = [];
    function bouncer(scuole) {
      return scuole.filter(item => item);
    }
    bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]);
    console.log(scuole);
```

But I still see `false` in console

Comment: filter returns a new array, it does not modify the original

Comment: Do you need only false values to be removed or all the falsy values to be removed?

Answer (score 2):

Check comments for explaination.

```
var scuole = []

function bouncer(scuole) {

// .filter returns a new filtered array and in following case
// filtered array will return an array whos value is 
// not equal to false 

     return scuole.filter(item => item !== false);

 }

//when calling bouncer function which returns an array
// we need to store that returned array to scuole variable
// for future use.
scuole = bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]);

// expected result [ null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]
console.log(scuole);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are *generally* not considered good. Please add some explanation to your code on how it works.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.filter` returns a new array, so you would have to assign it to a new variable. Also you currently do not filter, you dont process the item. Try this:

```
var someArray = [true, true, false, true];

function bouncer(array) {
return array.filter(item => item !== false);
}

var otherArray = bouncer(someArray);
// expected output: [true, true, true]
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Boolean` to cleanup all falsy values of an array.

```
const cleaned = [false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""].filter(Boolean);
// return "[]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `"filter"` function of JavaScript which will return you the filtered array. Please note, the filter will not update the original array hence you need to catch filtered array in a different array.

According to the snippet, I am returning the values except `false`. Let me know if you have any other issues or doubts.

```js
var original_arr = [false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]
var filtered_arr = original_arr.filter(function(item){return item != false})
console.log(filtered_arr);
```

Comment: where are you mentioning scuole array on the filter?

Comment: My bad! It's not in use. You can use your names as an array name. You can replace "original_arr" with "scuole"

Comment: original_arr is missing on the second filter

Comment: 0: null
1: NaN
2: undefined

Comment: Means? Can you explain? Your result should be like this?

Comment: Those 0,1,2 are the indexes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200242/discussion-between-rob-m-and-mayank-patel).

Answer (score 0):

```
 var scuole = [false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""];
scuole=  scuole.filter(item =>item!=false ||item!='false');
console.log(scuole);
```

you can do like this...

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
const arr = [ false, null, NaN, 0, undefined, true, 'string', 1, 'text', 4.3, '']; 
const newArr = arr.filter(e => e)
```

Should print out: `[ true, 'string', 1, 'text', 4.3 ]`