# Grab values from Nested Array only

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, request

My goal is to grab the values inside of `platforms` and retrieve back for example it as `windows, osx, linux`  And ultimately remove any empty sections that return back `undefined` when there is no `platforms[]` in the array

**Example of JSON Array that comes back**

```json
{
  "games": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "bundle_game": {
        "position": 1
      },
      "platforms": [
        "windows",
        "osx",
        "linux"
      ],
      "title": "xxx",
      "user": {
        "url": "https:xxx.io",
        "name": "xxxx",
        "id": 2
      },
      "url": "https:xxx and",
      "cover": "https:\\/\\/xxx.png",
      "cover_color": "#16211b",
      "classification": "game",
      "short_text": "ZZZZ",
      "price": "$xx"
    },
    {
      "id": 93664,
      "bundle_game": {
        "position": 2
      },
      "title": "Z",
      "user": {
        "url": "https:\\/\\/ZZZ",
        "name": "ZZZ",
        "id": 1
      },
      "url": "https:\\/\\/XXX",
      "cover": "https:\\/\\/XXX.png",
      "cover_color": "#000",
      "classification": "game",
      "short_text": "xxxx",
      "price": "$XX"
    }
  ]
}
```

**My Code**

```js
const request = require('request');
const _ = require("lodash");
const { json } = require('body-parser');

let url = "games.json";
let options = {json: true};
const platform = [];
request(url, options, (error, res, body) => {
    if (error) {
        return  console.log(error)
    };
    if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
    
        for (var i = 0; i <body.games.length; i++) { 

        var platformList = body.games[i].platforms;
        for(var j = 0; j < platformList .length; j++)
        {
            var listFilter= platformList [j];
                for(var e = 0; e < listFilter.length; e++)
            {
                var listFilter2= listFilter[e];
                console.log(listFilter2);
            }
        }    
    }
});
```

Comment: This question lacks a bit of information. Do you want to grab platforms for each game? and how do you want it returned?

Comment: hey @HeeysamH sorry about that. I just want whats inside of platforms returned. So for example `[ windows,osx, linux ], [ windows ] , [ osx, linux ] , [ osx ]` would be the return array. that way I can place it in MySQL.

Comment: So you want to turn one array of multiple items into 3 different arrays? Still, a bit faded what you want to achieve. Please edit the question and provide the expected return from the example JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get the `platforms` array data using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) & [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like:

```js
const games = [{
  "id": 1,
  "platforms": ["windows", "osx", "linux"],
  "title": "xxx",
}, {
  "id": 93664,
  "title": "Z",
}, {
  "id": 93665,
  "title": "Z2",
  "platforms": ["windows"],
}]

const listFilter = games.map(x => x.platforms).filter(Boolean)
console.log(listFilter)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For the demo purpose, I have used `games` variable here which represents `body.games` in your case.

Comment: @palaѕн `.filter(Boolean)` filters out falsy values?

Comment: Yes, you can read more details about it in the answer: [Remove all falsy values from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32906887)