# Remove different items from JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to solve an exercise where I need to create the function cleanArray and remove various items from an array. This is as far as I could get

```
function cleanArray(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === null || 0 || "" || false || undefined) {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
            return arr
        }
    }
}
```

But this only filters out `null` for me. I've tried putting the items to remove in a separate array or going one by one, but then it either returns `undefined` or only filters out the 0 even when it's not the first item to remove.

I've seen other answers where people use `filter` or `indexOf` but I want to see if there's a way to do it with `splice`. Is it not possible to use the logical operators here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values

Comment: comparisons have to be made as every time you do different check: you should read it as: "if `arr[i] === null`, or `arr[i] === 0`...or `arr[i] === undefined`; in all these cases do this..."

Comment: Duplicate of [Javascript: The prettiest way to compare one value against multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121395/javascript-the-prettiest-way-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values), but the unconditional `return` is still a problem. You can replace your entire code by `arr.filter(Boolean)`. Better target: [Remove all falsy values from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32906951/4642212).

Comment: @azibom What’s the point of your [edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28329532)? Please see [Should we approve suggested edits that change `\`\`\`` to four spaces code formatting or vice versa?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378962/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way you make multiple comparisons. Your if condition can be written as:

```
arr[i] === null || 0 === 1 || "" === 1 || false === 1 || undefined === 1
```

Now it is clear why it doesn't work, right? You need to compare `arr[i]` to every one of these values:

```
function cleanArray(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === null || arr[i] === 0 || arr[i] === "" || arr[i] === false || arr[i] === undefined) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
      return arr
    }
  }
}
```

Note: this approach probably won't work. Since you are removing elements from your array (and hence it is getting shorter and shorter), once an element is removed, you will be in the wrong index, and by the time you reach the end of your loop, you will encounter undefined index errors. Finally, move your return statement out of the loop.

I suggest
If you want to stay away from `Array.filter()`, I suggest creating a new array and only pushing in the values you want:

```
function cleanArray(arr) {
  var newArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === null || arr[i] === 0 || arr[i] === "" || arr[i] === false || arr[i] === undefined) {
      continue;
    } else {
      newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify this doing two simple steps.

1. Create a function to verify if a *primitive* value is *falsy*
2. Using a filter or reducer to isolate those values from the source array

Example:

```js
const array = [1,2,"", null, undefined, 3, "4", true, 5, false, "6"]

const isFalsy = value => !!value === false

// this one is just to make the code more readable
const isTrully = value => !isFalsy(value)

const trullyValues = array.reduce((a, c) => isFalsy(c) ? a : [...a, c], [])

// will return the same from above
const filteredyTrullyValues = array.filter(isTrully)
```

Comment: "I want to see if there's a way to do it with splice"

Comment: Why? `splice` is suitable for changes in your indexes and it mutates the source array. Also, it's more complex and less performant. Read your problem again and try to resolve by the simple way first. In a real world situation, you will introduce more problems by doing a filter operation using a `splice` instead of using `reduce` or `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

This will be enough:

```
if (!arr[i]) {
  arr.splice(i, 1);
  return arr
}
```

Because `null || 0 || "" || false || undefined` are evaluated to false.