# How do I count the number of truth values in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, foreach, boolean

I am struggling with some logic but I think I am close. Is there any way to get the number of truth values from an array of booleans?

```
  const checkedState = [true, false, true]

  function handleCourseProgress() {
    //for each value that is true in the array...
    checkedState.forEach((value) => {
      //if the value is true...
      if (value === true) {
        //count and total them up here....
        setCourseProgress(//return the count//);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Array.reduce() would probably be the easiest method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all falsy values from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906887/remove-all-falsy-values-from-an-array) - just count what's left after a filter.

Comment: Sure does! was not sure what method to use, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const checkedState = [false, true, false, true, true]

const count = checkedState.filter((value) => value).length
// Cleaner way
const anotherCount = checkedState.filter(Boolean).length

console.log(count)
console.log(anotherCount)
```

Basically filtering the array and looking for the truthy values and checking the length of the array will do the trick and after that you can call the `setCourseProgress(count)` with the right count value.

Answer (score 1):

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the elements that are `true`, and return the length of that array.

```js
const one = [false, true, true];
const two = [true, true, true];
const three = [false, false, false, false];

function trueElements(arr) {
  return arr.filter(b => b).length;
}

console.log(trueElements(one));
console.log(trueElements(two))
console.log(trueElements(three))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

**Filter** for the value you want and then count the length of the filtered:

```
const filterQuantity = checkedState.filter((x) => x === true).length;
```

**Reduce** will process each entry and determine if we need to increment if true:

```
const reduceQuantity = checkedState.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
  return (currentValue) ? previousValue + 1 : previousValue;
}, 0);
```

Snippet:

```js
const checkedState = [true, false, true];

const filterQuantity = checkedState.filter((x) => x === true).length;

const reduceQuantity = checkedState.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
  return (currentValue) ? previousValue + 1 : previousValue;
}, 0);

console.info(filterQuantity, reduceQuantity);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is with reduce. Here's the example.

```js
const checkedState = [true, false, true]

const answer = checkedState.reduce((acc, val) => val ? acc + val : acc);

console.log(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is `[true, false, true].filter(x=>x).length`